# Content Slider stop and start in accordion

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have code below for a Pure CSS content slider in an accordion I have created. Is it possible to start and stop the Content Slider when the accordion is opened and closed? Currently the Content Slider keeps running even if the accordion is closed. Is this possible with Pure CSS? If not would this be possible with Vanilla JavaScript (no JQuery). Anything helps, cheers.

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/* Acordeon styles */

.tab {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bold {
  font-weight:bold;
  color: #005bab;
  }

.top {
  margin-top:-20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size:13px;
}

.input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.label {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 0 0 1em;
  color: #005bab;
  background: #e2ecf6;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 6;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.label:hover {
  background-color: #d2e2ef;
}

.tab-content {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: max-height .5s;
  -o-transition: max-height .5s;
  transition: max-height .5s;
  padding-left: 35px;
  background: #dce7f2;
}

.tab-content .container {
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0.75);
  -webkit-transition: transform 0.75s, opacity .75s;
  -o-transition: transform 0.75s, opacity .75s;
  transition: transform 0.75s, opacity .75s;
  background: #f4f8fc;
}


/* :checked */

.input:checked~.tab-content {
  max-height: 35em;
}

.input:checked~.tab-content .container {
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}

/* Icon */

.label::after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  line-height: 3;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s;
  -o-transition: all .35s;
  transition: all .35s;
}

.input[type=checkbox]+.label::after {
  content: "+";
}

.input[type=radio]+.label::after {
  content: "";
}

.input[type=checkbox]:checked+.label::after {
  transform: rotate(315deg);
}

.input[type=radio]:checked+.label::after {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

.bottombar {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #00688B;
}


/* all position:absolute removed */
#scroller {
overflow:hidden;
}

#scroller .innerScrollArea {

}

#scroller ul {
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  display:flex;/* UPDATE */
}

#scroller li {
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.circle {
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color:transparent;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:5px;
  border-color:#006850;
}

.circle-text {
  color: #1f497d;
  font-family:Verdana;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  top: 45px;
  margin-left:-35px;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
}

.circleinv{
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color:transparent;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:5px;
  border-color:transparent;
}

.arrow {
  width:145px;
  height:45px;
}

.arrowinv {
  visibility:hidden;
  width:145px;
  height:50px;
}

.flipimage {
  width:145px;
  height:45px;
  -moz-transform: scaleY(-1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleY(-1);
    transform: scaleY(-1);
    -ms-filter: fliph; /*IE*/
    filter: fliph; /*IE*/
}

/* UPDATE  for animation */
.ul {
  animation: slidli 90s infinite linear;
}
.ul:hover {
  animation-play-state:paused;
}
@keyframes slidli {
  100% {
    transform:translatex(-733.5%);/* this is to be update to the content with to see every element slide once untill copies/clone comes back at same spot */ 
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="top"> 
   <p> 
      <span style="font-family: verdana;"><strong>Click the &quot;</strong><span class="ms-rteThemeForeColor-5-0"><strong>+</strong></span><strong>&quot; to expand and the &quot;</strong><span class="ms-rteThemeForeColor-5-0"><strong>x</strong></span><strong>&quot; to collapse</strong></span></p> 
</div> 
<div class="wrapper">
  
  
  
  <div class="tab">
    <input name="tabs" class="input" id="tab-one" type="checkbox"/>
         <label class="label" for="tab-one">Content Slider</label>
         <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="container">
              
                      <div class="everything">
  <div id="scroller" style="width: 400px; height: 255px; margin: 0 auto;">
    <div class="innerScrollArea">
      <ul class="ul">
        <li>
          <br style="line-height:49px;"/>
          <div class="circle">
            <div class="circle-text">
              HR Connect<br/>Service<br/>Representative
            </div>
          </div>
          <img class="flipimage" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1499184462/testarrow_yhblyv.png">
        </li>
        <li>
          <img class="arrow" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1499184462/testarrow_yhblyv.png">
          <div class="circle">
            <div class="circle-text">
              Employee<br/>Relations<br/>Specialist
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <br style="line-height:49px;"/>
          <div class="circle">
            <div class="circle-text">
              Employee<br/>Relations<br/>Manager
            </div>
          </div>
          <img class="flipimage" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1499184462/testarrow_yhblyv.png">
        </li>
        <li>
<img class="arrowinv" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1499184462/testarrow_yhblyv.png">
          <div class="circle">
            <div class="circle-text">
              Director, Employee<br/>Relations &<br/>Well-Being
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
                <li>
          <div class="circleinv">
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="circleinv">
          </div>
        </li>
        
        <!--Dupes-->
        
                <li>
          <br style="line-height:49px;"/>
          <div class="circle">
            <div class="circle-text">
              HR Connect<br/>Service<br/>Representative
            </div>
          </div>
          <img class="flipimage" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1499184462/testarrow_yhblyv.png">
        </li>
        <li>
          <img class="arrow" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1499184462/testarrow_yhblyv.png">
          <div class="circle">
            <div class="circle-text">
              Employee<br/>Relations<br/>Specialist
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <br style="line-height:49px;"/>
          <div class="circle">
            <div class="circle-text">
              Employee<br/>Relations<br/>Manager
            </div>
          </div>
          <img class="flipimage" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1499184462/testarrow_yhblyv.png">
        </li>
        <li>
<img class="arrowinv" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1499184462/testarrow_yhblyv.png">
          <div class="circle">
            <div class="circle-text">
              Director, Employee<br/>Relations &<br/>Well-Being
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
                <li>
          <div class="circleinv">
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="circleinv">
          </div>
        </li>
        
        <!--Dupe 2-->
        
                <li>
          <br style="line-height:49px;"/>
          <div class="circle">
            <div class="circle-text">
              HR Connect<br/>Service<br/>Representative
            </div>
          </div>
          <img class="flipimage" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1499184462/testarrow_yhblyv.png">
        </li>
        <li>
          <img class="arrow" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1499184462/testarrow_yhblyv.png">
          <div class="circle">
            <div class="circle-text">
              Employee<br/>Relations<br/>Specialist
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <br style="line-height:49px;"/>
          <div class="circle">
            <div class="circle-text">
              Employee<br/>Relations<br/>Manager
            </div>
          </div>
          <img class="flipimage" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1499184462/testarrow_yhblyv.png">
        </li>
        <li>
<img class="arrowinv" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1499184462/testarrow_yhblyv.png">
          <div class="circle">
            <div class="circle-text">
              Director, Employee<br/>Relations &<br/>Well-Being
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
                <li>
          <div class="circleinv">
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="circleinv">
          </div>
        </li>
        
        <!--Dupe 3-->
        
                <li>
          <br style="line-height:49px;"/>
          <div class="circle">
            <div class="circle-text">
              HR Connect<br/>Service<br/>Representative
            </div>
          </div>
          <img class="flipimage" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1499184462/testarrow_yhblyv.png">
        </li>
        <li>
          <img class="arrow" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1499184462/testarrow_yhblyv.png">
          <div class="circle">
            <div class="circle-text">
              Employee<br/>Relations<br/>Specialist
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <br style="line-height:49px;"/>
          <div class="circle">
            <div class="circle-text">
              Employee<br/>Relations<br/>Manager
            </div>
          </div>
          <img class="flipimage" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1499184462/testarrow_yhblyv.png">
        </li>
        <li>
<img class="arrowinv" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1499184462/testarrow_yhblyv.png">
          <div class="circle">
            <div class="circle-text">
              Director, Employee<br/>Relations &<br/>Well-Being
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
                <li>
          <div class="circleinv">
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="circleinv">
          </div>
        </li>
        
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
              
            </div>
         </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="bottombar"></div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would normally advise that you do this kind of stuff with JS but if you want to avoid it here's a working (albeit verbose) solution:

replace

```
.ul:hover {
  animation-play-state:paused;
}
```

with

```
.input:checked~.tab-content .container .ul:hover {
  animation-play-state:paused;
}

.tab-content .container .ul{
  animation-play-state:paused;
}
.input:checked~.tab-content .container .ul {
  animation-play-state:running;
}
```

Here's a pen showing the solution.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zzaKow

Comment: Just corrected a typo. Make sure you replace the hover version and not the regular ul class.